# How to connect several 4K monitors to ASUS GL552VW laptop?

Tags: multiple-monitors, display-resolution, adapter

I am going to buy laptop ASUS GL552VW. But first I'd like to know if it's possible to connect serveral 4K monitors to it.

That laptop has:

- HDMI port
- 1 x USB 2.0
- 2 x USB 3.0
- 1 x USB 3.1 Type-C
- graphics: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 960M

OK. One 4K monitor can be plugged in into HDMI.
The question is how to connect more one/two 4K monitor/monitors?

p.s. There are some adapters USB 3.1 Type-C to Display Port in shops. Does anybody know if they are compatible with Ubuntu? If yes, will it supoort 4K resolution (3840x2160)?

UPDATE: I don't need in high performance as I don't play games.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Ubuntu and is a hardware related problem. Those go to http://superuser.com/

Comment: This is a question about what your specific hardware supports in terms of compatibility with other hardware, and is not about Ubuntu. Therefore it is off topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue here is bandwidth. According to this [source](http://www.displayport.org/cables/driving-multiple-displays-from-a-single-displayport-output/) which goes into detail about dasiy-chaining multiple displays using one DisplayPort 1.2 output shows that it will only support one 4K (3840x2160) display due to bandwidth issues. Taking this into account, [DisplayPort 1.2 has an effective bandwidth of 17.28 Gbit/s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayPort#1.2) whereas [USB Type-C (USB 3.1 Gen2) has a maximum bandwidth of 10 Gbit/s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#USB_3.1). This suggests that USB Type-C lacks the required bandwidth to run more than one display at 4K resolutions.

There is also the GPU to consider, according to product page for the [ASUS GL552VW](http://store.asus.com/us/item/201510AM170008064/A18486) the GTX 960M has 2 Gigabytes of GDDR5 and at the time of writing I am using two displays on Ubuntu 15.10, one is an ultra-wide @ 2560x1080 and other one is 4K @ 3840x2160 and the memory usage on my GTX 970 is 1207MB. With your proposed setup you'd be running three 4K displays @ 3840x2160 each and the display on the laptop which is 1080p, this would certainly over-strips the 2 Gigabytes of GDDR5 easily.

At this juncture you are best looking for a laptop with two mini displayport and one HDMI connector providing the GPU is capable of powering all those displays.

Comment: How did you connected your 2 monitors? Using a splitter on the HDMI port?